# How do I import UnionFind<T> to IntelliJ? (Java)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jgrapht, union-find

I want to import [this](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org.jgrapht.core/org/jgrapht/alg/util/UnionFind.html) UnionFind- class to my IntelliJ project. But I get a Maven error I do not understand. When I try and type `import org.jgrapht.alg.util.UnionFind<T>;` in the beginning of my project, I get an error saying

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'jgrapht'
```

I get the option to `add Maven dependency...`, but when I click on it this

[image: this]

window pops up.
I don't know what Maven is, and I am scared to alter anything whn I don't know how it works.

Comment: Have you imported the dependency in your pom.xml file from Maven repository?

Comment: I don't know how to check this. I got help setting up IntelliJ and I haven't encountered this problem before.

Comment: I assume you have a pom.xml file right? Add the answer to your maven file

Comment: [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) is a dependency management tool. When your project depends on (uses) libraries that are not part of the standard Java libraries that come with the JDK, you can use Maven to manage them (download the jar files and associate them with your project).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to import the dependency in your `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
    <artifactId>jgrapht-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

[Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jgrapht/jgrapht-core/1.5.1)

[UnionFind](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.jgrapht/jgrapht-core/1.2.0/source-code/org/jgrapht/alg/util/UnionFind.java) class is in this dependency.